# Spivak's Question 2-25

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I haven't been able to find a solution to this online.  The question is as follows.

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-x^{-2}}\qquad&x\ne0\\
0&x=0
\end{cases}$$
Show that $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function, and $f^{(i)}(0)=0$ for all $i$.

My solution is as follows.

Since the derivative is only in one variable, the order of the derivative is immaterial and so it is automatically $C^\infty$.  To show that $f^{(i)}(0)=0$, first let us differentiate it once
$$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
which can be rewritten to
$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{-1/h}{e^{h^{-2}}}$$
Applying L'Hopital's rule (or L'Hospital I'm not entirely sure)
$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h}{2e^{h^{-2}}}$$
What I am unclear about is how this helps show that it tends to zero, since the more I apply L'Hopitals the higher the power on the numerator increases (it always increases by 2 because differentiating the denominator brings in a factor of $h^{-3}$ which cancels out the decrease of 1 from differentiating the numerator).  Even after applying L'Hopitals it seems to return $0/\infty$.  I've thought about rewriting it as
$$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-h^{-2}}}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h^2}{2}\cdot\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-h^{-2}}}{h}$$
and reason that the only number that is itself after multiplication is zero but I think that seems very flimsy (since it would also be fulfilled by infinity).

How much of my answer is wrong and what have I not considered that leads to the answer?

Comment: The first L'hopital is correct.  But then you have $0/\infty$ which is zero and doesn't need another L'Hopital

Comment: I thought $0/\infty$ was one of the indeterminate forms that requires L'Hopital.

Comment: @Empy2 you're right do you want to write it as an answer and I'll give it a tick?

Comment: @Empy2 is the reasoning for $C^\infty$ correct as well?

Comment: For $C^{\infty}$ No, for example $x|x|$ has a first derivative at zero, but not a second derivative there.  (It is $x^2$ for positive $x$ and $-(x^2)$ for negative $x$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first l'Hopital is correct because it is in the form $\infty/\infty$.  But the second time it has the form $0/\infty$, so has limit $0$, and doesn't need l'Hopital.
For $C^\infty$, there are functions such as $x|x|$ which have a first derivative but not a second derivative, so $C^\infty$ is not automatic.  Show the $n$th derivative is a polynomial divided by the exponential, and show that limit is always zero.